# Тестовая стратегия/тестовый сценарий/test-case как я это понял

Tags: тестирование, теория

не так давно изучаю тестирование и хотел бы расставить все точки над i. Есть задание "...придумайте тестовую стратегию: кратко перечислите тестовые сценарии, которые вы собираетесь тестировать. Выберите 2 сценария,  и напишите test case для каждого из них...". Собсна вопрос, как я понял из теории: тестовая стратегия - это то как мы тестируем продукт, туда входит сбор информации о продукте, анализ полученной информации, ну и собсно принятие решений где мы пишем как и почему мы будем проводить наши тесты исходя из двух прошлых пунктов.

А вот с остальными двумя терминами выходит засада. Почти везде пишут что тестовый сценарий это и есть test-case и выглядит он как "Ожидание: программа закрывается сочетанием клавиш Alt-f4. Действие: при включенной программе используем данное сочетание клавиш. Результат: Успешно. Программа закрывается"

Или Тестовый сценарий это набор неких шаблонов типа: "запустить программу, проверить активные кнопки, проверить возможность ввода текста, проверить удаление текста, etc...". А test-case в этом случае это уже подробные проверки каждого шаблона-шага, типа декомпозиция "Запустить программу: программа запускается из папки, программа запускается из командной строки, программа запускается из Пуск. Проверить активные кнопки: кнопка help при нажатии выдает то-то и то-то" ну и так далее, надеюсь понятно к чему я клоню.
Я немного подзапутался во всей этой тестовой документации, надеюсь вам будет не в тяготу направить меня на путь истинный. заранее всем добра!